# Authorization header in nginx subrequest is missed

Tags: nginx, authorization, nginx-reverse-proxy

I tried to configure auth sub request like this [documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-subrequest-authentication)

Client send request with **authorization** header to protected resource via nginx.
But when nginx send subrequest to check access, **authorization** header in subrequest is missed.

i tried to use this parameters in auth location:

`proxy_set_header authorization $http_authorization;`

But it didn't get result.

Answer (score 3):

Special nginx variables like `$http_<name>` are not shared with the subrequests (**update**: this is a wrong assumption, request headers actualy **gets** shared with the subrequests, see the update to the answer). That internal nginx subrequests API is very special thing, many modules that makes use of it do not even share variable containers between main request and subrequests. However the `auth_request_module` is some kind of exception, making possible a workaround using the intermediate variable:

```
location /auth {
    proxy_set_header Authorization $main_auth;
    proxy_pass ...
}
location / {
    set $main_auth $http_authorization;
    auth_request /auth;
    ...
}
```

---

Ok, after testing this myself I can state a couple of facts.

1. `Authorization` header (as well as other main request headers) **gets** added to the subrequest. However it can be redefined for the subrequest explicitly:

   ```
   location /auth {
       proxy_set_header Authorization "sub";
       proxy_pass ...
   }
   ```

   or removed from the subrequest completely:

   ```
   location /auth {
       proxy_set_header Authorization "";
       proxy_pass ...
   }
   ```
2. Intermediate variable **does** work for passing data from main request to the subrequest made by `auth_request_module`:

   ```
   location /auth {
       proxy_set_header X-From $from;
       proxy_pass ...
   }
   location / {
       set $from "from-main";
       auth_request /auth;
       ...
   }
   ```

   An auth backend **will** receive the `X-From: from-main` HTTP header.

Comment: I set $main_auth intermediate variable as in your answer but I still got error - no  header

Comment: Ok, I tested this myself and add the test results to the answer. You can define custom log format adding `$http_authorization` variable to be logged and check if the incoming request actually contains the `Authorization` header or it get lost somewhere in the middle.

Comment: Ivan thanks for answers, they was helpfull. I resolved this issue and posted answer.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was with CORS requests.
OPTIONS request didn't contain **Authorization** header. And auth service returned error.

Solution:

```
location /backend {
    auth_request                /auth;
    proxy_pass                  http://backend;
}
location /auth {
    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        return 200;
    }
    proxy_pass                  http://auth;
}
```